# mining for quark

Tags: miner-configuration, terminology

I installed quarkcoin-qt and wanted to see if I can get it to mine any quarks.

I opened the necessary port and it synchronized.

I opened its console window and connected to the network using

```
addnode 54.193.30.6 onetry
addnode 54.224.185.35 onetry
addnode 54.200.66.187 onetry
addnode 54.201.33.23; onetry
addnode 86.183.230.58; onetry
addnode 119.252.247.163 onetry
addnode 218.30.67.157 onetry
```

and then used `setgenerate true -1` to (supposedly) put it into mining mode...

calling `getmininginfo` it returns

```
{
"blocks" : 420230,
"currentblocksize" : 2978,
"currentblocktx" : 3,
"difficulty" : 2856.00406965,
"errors" : "",
"generate" : true,
"genproclimit" : -1,
"hashespersec" : 74772,
"pooledtx" : 3,
"testnet" : false
}
```

Where can I read about the meaning of all this information?

Is there anything else I need to do? or should I just wait now?
And If I only have to wait  then how long until I am supposed to see anything?

Comment: I tried this but after about 2 hours I still never received a response at my wallet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point, all you need to do is wait. As for the getmininginfo...

- blocks = number of blocks mined
- currentblocksize = size of blocks in bytes
- currentblocktx = number of transactions included in the block
- difficulty = how hard it is to mine
- errors = any error messages (you have none which is good)
- generate = if you are mining or not (true = you are mining)
- hashespersec = how fast you are mining
- pooledtx = number of transactions in the memory pool
- testnet = if you are running on testnet or not (false = you are mining real coins, not test coins)

Comment: How do you get the number of blocks found by your miner?

Answer (score 1):

Also refer to guide on official forum.

http://quark.freeforums.net/thread/141/mine-quarkcoin-ultimate-mining-guide

It will be more profit if you will mine in pool and using optimized miners.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion for use a pool. after getting nothing in about 48 hours with the wallet I went along and used an optimized miner with a pool ( qrk.coinmine.pl ) and I now see it actually mining...
Do you know of a working 32bit miner?

Answer (score 0):

I tried out the http://reviewoutlaw.com/how-to-start-mining-quarks-bitcoins-mining-the-simple-guide/

Seemed to work the Best